# Php Script is Not Emailing $_SESSIONized variable values upon submission

Tags: php, email, session

I have a php file **php1.php** that has session variables created

```
<?php 
session_start();
#pathway var
$path=$_GET['path'];
$education=$_GET['edu'];
$cert=$_GET['cert'];
$server_prefix = 'https://';
$server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

$_SESSION['pathid']=$path;
$_SESSION['edid']=$education;
$_SESSION['certid']=$cert;
?>

<a href="#" class="contact" id="pathwayshare">Share this pathway!</a>
```

When a user clicks on the link above, it brings up a *modal* window.

The user fills out some form inputs, which is then handled by **php2.php**:

```
 session_start();
    if ($action == "send") {
        //added
        #pathway var
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        $pathval = $_SESSION['pathid'];
        $edval = $_SESSION['edid'];
        $certval = $_SESSION['certid'];

        var_dump($pathval);
        var_dump($edval);
        var_dump($certval);

        $data = array(
            "path"=>$pathval,
            "edu"=>$edval,
            "cert"=>$certval
        );

        var_dump($data);


        $server_prefix = 'https://';
        $server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

        #$fullurl = $server_prefix.$server_address."/career/pathway?ed=".$edval;

        // Send the email
        $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
        $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
        $subject = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : $subject;
        $message = 'message: '.$server_prefix.$server_address.'/career/pathway?'.http_build_query($data);
        var_dump($message);
        // $message = $pathval;
        var_dump($message);

        $cc = isset($_POST["cc"]) ? $_POST["cc"] : "";
        $token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";

        // make sure the token matches
        if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
            smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $message, $cc);
            echo "Your message was successfully sent.";
            // echo $name . "\n";
            // echo $email . "\n";
            // echo $subject . "\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "Unfortunately, your message could not be verified.";
        }
    }

function smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $message, $cc) {
    global $to, $extra;

    // Filter and validate fields
    $name = smcf_filter($name);
    $subject = smcf_filter($subject);
    $email = smcf_filter($email);
    if (!smcf_validate_email($email)) {
        $subject .= " - invalid email";
        $message .= "\n\nBad email: $email";
        $email = $to;
        $cc = 0; // do not CC "sender"
    }

    // Add additional info to the message
    if ($extra["ip"]) {
        $message .= "\n\nIP: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    if ($extra["user_agent"]) {
        $message .= "\n\nUSER AGENT: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    }

    // Set and wordwrap message body
    $body = "From: Sender\n\n";
    $body .= "Message: $message";
    $body = wordwrap($body, 70);

    // Build header
    $headers = "From: $email\n";
    if ($cc == 1) {
        $headers .= "Cc: $email\n";
    }
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/SimpleModalContactForm";

    // UTF-8
    if (function_exists('mb_encode_mimeheader')) {
        $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, "UTF-8", "B", "\n");
    }
    else {
        // you need to enable mb_encode_mimeheader or risk 
        // getting emails that are not UTF-8 encoded
    }
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";

    // Send email
    @mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) or 
        die("Unfortunately, a server issue prevented delivery of your message.");
}
```

This **php2.php** sets up the email and sends it. The issue is, my `var_dump($message)` statements are outputting correct values like:

```
array(3) { ["pathid"]=> string(1) "3" ["edid"]=> string(1) "4" ["certid"]=> string(0) "" } string(1) "3" string(1) "4" string(0) "" array(3) { ["path"]=> string(1) "3" ["edu"]=> string(1) "4" ["cert"]=> string(0) "" } string(65) "message: https://xx.xx.xx.x.x/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=" string(65) "message: https://xx.xx.xx.x.x/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=" Your message was successfully sent.
```

This last `$message` value of `message: https://xx.xx.xx.x.x/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=` is accurate and is what I want to include in the email, the problem is, the info sent in an email is:
message: `https://xx.xx.xx.x.x/career/pathway?path=edu=cert` which is incorrect as none of the parameters are sent for `path` , `edu` , `cert` in the url - what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: Yes i did start the sessions. updated.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have for `mail()` and anything else relevant to mail?

Comment: Included as part of php2.php; see function smcf_send()

Comment: I spotted a missing `.` for `$body = wordwrap($body, 70);` which could be part of the problem. That concatenate is lost/broken. So replace it with `$body .= wordwrap($body, 70);` - might even fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for trying, unfortunately that didnt fix this issue. The portion creating this message in the email is this line: `$body .= "Message: $message";`